# Move image left and right inside outer circle android

Tags: android, android-layout, transition, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I have two images one is a big circle and another is a camera image in center of circle.

What I need: I can touch camera image and I want to move left and right inside the outer circle so when I move camera image left I want to open One Activity and when I move right I want to open different Activity.

```
img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) img.getLayoutParams();
            //LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) img.getLayoutParams();
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int eid = event.getAction();
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
            switch (eid) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                x = (int) event.getRawX();      
                mParams.leftMargin = x - 100;
                img.setLayoutParams(mParams);

                y = (int) event.getRawY();
                mParams.rightMargin = y - 100;
                img.setLayoutParams(mParams);
              //  touchMove(x, y);

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //touchStart(x, y);
                    break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                startDirection = direction;
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

     <RelativeLayout
         android:id="@+id/rectangle"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:paddingLeft="10dp"
         android:paddingRight="10dp"
         android:background="@drawable/outer_circle" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="hello_world"
            android:src="@drawable/camera" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run this its moves left but going out from the circle and when I move right the outer circle get stretched.

Answer (score 0):

You are giving your ImageView a RelativeLayout type Params object as I see. Can't be sure because the type of your /img/ variable cannot be seen.

If the touched view is what you want to move, you could also
use the functions already declared /v/ View varlable, all you need to do
is cast it to an ImageView.

The stretching is some kind of weird. Is this the whole layout file? So your actual layout is
a RelativeLayout with a background of a circle?

Comment: yes Lazli my layout is a relative with background of circle and yes i want to move imaveview inside relative layout.

Comment: private ImageView img;

img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);